# Calculate duplicated letters next to each other

Tags: javascript

I need to calculate pairs of same letters that stay each other in twos, I got this code

```
const calculateLetters = (text: string) => {
  const arrayStr = [...text];

  let count = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arrayStr.length; i++) {
    if (arrayStr[i] === arrayStr[i + 1]) {
      count += 1;
    }
  }

  return count;
};

console.log(calculateLetters('ABBAAA'));
```

But now it returns 3, what I need to do is make count equal 2, because I need to calculate pairs of same letters.

Comment: This is the correct output.  There are 3 pairs of letters in your string.

Comment: If you are counting pairs of letters then i think 3 is correct for your `ABBAAA` example. First pair is `BB`, and then on the `AAA` there are two pairs (the first 2 letters and the last 2 letters)

Comment: Yea but i need to get rid of the last item cuz pair of a already exists before

Comment: If you always get rid of already present pairs then the answer will  always be 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with `RegEx` The below pattern will count matches of the same character pairs.

```js
const countPairs = (text) => {
  //Grab the matches length if any exist, otherwise return 0
  return (text.match(/(.)\1/g))?.length ?? 0
}
console.log(countPairs("abc")) //Result is 0
console.log(countPairs("ABBAAA")) //Result is 2
console.log(countPairs("aabBccDD111")) //Result is 4
```

With your code, you just need to move past the match when you find one

```js
const calculateLetters = (text) => {
  const arrayStr = [...text];

  let count = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arrayStr.length; i++) {
    if (arrayStr[i] === arrayStr[i + 1]) {
      count += 1;
      //move past the match
      i++;
    }
  }

  return count;
};

console.log(calculateLetters('ABBAAA'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement, if you've found a pair, then iterate till the point your i+1th element is not same as ith element, and then count again.

Answer (score -1):

```
const calculateLetters = (text: string) => {
  const arrayStr = [...text];

  let count = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arrayStr.length; i++) {
    let j = i;
    while(i + 1 < arrayStr.length && arrayStr[i] === arrayStr[i + 1]) {
      i+= 1;
    }
    if(i != j){
      count += 1;
    }
  }

  return count;
};

console.log(calculateLetters('ABBAAA'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Define a `zip` function that can be used to create a list of pairs of adjacent letters in the text. Then count the pairs that match.

Since you want unique adjacent letters, pass the pairs through a `Set` before counting.

```
const zip = (a, b) => a.map((k, i) => [k, b[i]])


const calculateLetters = (text) => {
  const chars = [...text]

  const adjacentLetters = zip(chars, chars.slice(1))

  const uniqueAdjacentLetters = [
    ...new Set(adjacentLetters.map(([a,b]) => `${a}:${b}`))
  ].map(x => x.split(':'))

  const count = uniqueAdjacentLetters.reduce(
    (total, [a,b]) => total + ((a === b) ? 1 : 0),
    0,
  )

  return count
}

console.log(calculateLetters('ABBAAA'))
```

Comment: This method has issue with readability and performance.

Comment: Agreed, it's not performant.  Hopefully, it offers some perspective on a different way to solve the problem.